# How to run my map-reduce program with AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

I`m trying to run a map-reduce program using Hadoop framework.
I need to run the program on an AmazonElasticMapReduce instance but I keep getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.transform.JsonErrorUnmarshaller: method (Ljava/lang/Class;)V not found

I tried to fix my pom file and adding the AWS SDK, changing its versions and adding the core separately.

my pom.xml file:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ec2</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-emr</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

me trying to create the instance:

```
AWSCredentials creds = new PropertiesCredentials(new FileInputStream(propertiesFilePath));

AmazonElasticMapReduce mapReduce = new AmazonElasticMapReduceClient(creds);
```

I expect the program to run on AWS instance (and probably get a bunch more error in my code that I can debug).

Comment: Note: Do not mix AWS dependency or Hadoop versions